# EXT JS: For a datefield how to change the background color for the calendar that pops up

Tags: extjs

I have a datefield in ExtJS.

```
 {
     xtype: 'datefield',
     anchor: '100%',
     itemId: 'Date',
     emptyText: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
     name: 'date',
     fieldLabel: 'From Date',
     labelStyle: 'font-family:Arial;font-style:normal;font-size:12px;text-align:right;',
     margin: "10 5 5 5"
  }
```

The calendar that pops up has the background and the dates written on it in black. Is there any way I can change the font color/background color to white? 
I went through the Senchs docs but didn't find anything useful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use CSS :

```
.x-datepicker-inner {
    background-color: #bada55 !important;
}

.x-datepicker-date {
    color: red !important;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/W4aDB/1/